# Razorpay gateway is not working in in-app browser like instagram browser

Tags: browser, instagram, razorpay

I am using RazorPay gateway in my Laravel project where razorpay works fine in normal browser like in Chrome, Opera, etc.

But when it comes to mobile app like instagram where it provides in-app browser. When we click on link on instagram it opens its browser in app where razorpay payment is not working.

In debit card section, it asks all the required information like card number, expiry date, CVV and after this page gets blank. That banks OTP page is not loading.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem ? It's not working for us as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a lot I found the solution.

Just add this line to `<head>` tag

`<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

Everything works fine

Comment: Still the same for me even after making adding the above tag. Am I missing anything? Also the issue is only on instagram (Meta). It's working fine on telegram webview.