# Razorpay Showing This Browser is not supported , Please try payment in another browser

Tags: php, angular, payment-gateway, payment, razorpay

I have Integrated Razorpay in my website which is build on php backend and Angular frontend and while testing on localhost:4200 its showing alert in the browser - **This browser is not supported. Please try payment with another browser.**

I integrated Razorpay to my website , it expected to redirect to razorpay payment gateway page where I can select the payment method and then pay the amount , but before redirecting it shows. **This browser is not supported. Please try payment with another browser**

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried using a different one?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60881035/razorpay-gateway-is-not-working-in-in-app-browser-like-instagram-browser

Comment: Actually I have tried in all browsers but sometimes it works fine but some time it shows that Browser is not supported. I have tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60881035/razorpay-gateway-is-not-working-in-in-app-browser-like-instagram-browser but that didn't work.